# OpenCV function to convert 8U image to 16U

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

Is anyone aware of any functions in OpenCV which support `8U` to `16U` conversion? I tried `cvConvertImage`, `cvConvertScale` but they are all meant to operate only on `8U` image formats.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the newer C++ API, then check out `Mat::convertTo`

```
Mat a(rows, cols, CV_8U);
Mat b;
a.convertTo(b, CV_16U);
```

Comment: you mean to say that there is no equivalent C API to do this?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, you can always roll your own C function by accessing the 8U buffer data directly, casting up from unsigned char to unsigned short, and assigning to your 16U CvMat.

Comment: If you want the image to appear the same after the conversion, you will also need to apply a scale factor: a.convertTo(b, CV_16U, 65535 / 255);